# Pass data to click event callback in Highstock chart with more then 1000 entries

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart where I display additional data to every point beneath the chart. Therefor I pass the id of the data object into the point data of the series. When someone click on a point in the charts I can read the id from `event.point.id` in the callback. Unfortunately this only works with less the 1000 points. Event if I set turboThreshold to 2000 the additional data are missing in the `event.point` object.

A series look like this

```
series:{
  data: [{x:1, y:2, id:'someId'}]
  turboThreshold: 2000
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take look at simple example http://jsfiddle.net/GRUjw/1 which has 2000 points and ids. Information about point's id is displayed in div.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold:3000,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        $('#report').html('Clicked point\'s id: '+this.id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/456) I have to disable `dataGrouping` for the series as well

```
series:{
  data: [{x:1, y:2, id:'someId'}]
  turboThreshold: 2000,
    dataGrouping: {
     enabled: false
  }
}
```